# Follow the plan vs follow through with the plan

Tags: difference

What’s the difference between saying ‘I will follow the plan’ and ‘I will follow through with the plan’? I have encountered both constructions but couldn’t figure out the difference in meaning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dictionaries tell that to "follow through" is "to finish all aspects of a task"

"To follow the plan" is just doing what the plan says. Regardless of you finishing the task or not

So to "follow through with the plan" is to follow the plan until the end and finish all tasks in the plan